# Constrain a column based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following query in which I am interested in only 3 columns:

```
SELECT CustomerID, Country, IF(Country="Mexico", City, null) City FROM Customers;
```

Basically it retrieves the city for a country that I am interested in. Otherwise it returns null.
My question is that if I have a huge number of records, is the query faster than this query:

```
SELECT CustomerID, Country, City FROM Customers;
```

In other words, does constraining the values using if statement make the query slower?

Comment: Sligthly slower, but nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first query has to do additional conditional logic.  This requires slightly more processing.  On the other hand, the volume of data returned is slightly smaller (because of the `NULL` values) so this might balance out.

However, you are returning large volumes of data from the table and the real constraint on performance is reading the data.

So, the difference in the two should be very slight.

On the other hand, if you are interested only in one country, then use `WHERE`:

```
SELECT CustomerID, Country, City
FROM Customers c
WHERE Country = 'Mexico';
```

This returns a smaller amount of data so it should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is minimal.

The cost of your query is usually based on the I/O block access and number of rows. The extra computed column barely makes any difference.